# any advice to address spark streaming's processing time peak every 10 seconds?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I run a program using spark streaming to consume kafka data to do real time statistics.
When the `numPartitions` param in the function `reduceByKeyAndWindow` is not set, the processing time is very odd. It peak every 10s. 
[processing time picture linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBx4I.png)
All the code is following. Although when `numPartitions` is set 1 this situation can be addressed, there is situation that `numPartitions` greater 1 is needed to process data.

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.set('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', "-Xss30M")
ctx = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingIDCount", conf=conf)
ctx.setLogLevel('FATAL')
ctx.setCheckpointDir('./checkpoint')
streaming_ctx = StreamingContext(ctx, 1)  # s
broker, topic = "127.0.0.1:9092", ["spark"]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streaming_ctx, topic, {"metadata.broker.list": broker})
lines = kvs.map(lambda items: items[1])
counts = lines. \
    map(lambda ip: (ip, 1)). \
    reduceByKeyAndWindow(lambda a, b: a + b, lambda a, b: a - b, 60, 1)
```

I don't know what is happening. Can any body help me?

Comment: There is other information than may be needed.
1. kafka message is just a string.
2. most of the message is distinct from each other